# Identify segmentation fault with valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this C++ program:

I have an array of size 2 which I initialize to 0.
Afterwards I am accessing an element out of bounds of the array. However, I am getting any error with valgrind.

I am compiling the code as:

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test
```

And running valgrind with:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file="log.txt" ./test


int main() 
{
    int foo[2] = {0};
    std::cout << foo[0] << std::endl;
    foo[5] = 12; // out of bounds

    return 0;
}
```

The log is:

```
==3560== Command: ./test
==3560== Parent PID: 3474
==3560== 
==3560== 
==3560== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3560==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3560==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==3560== 
==3560== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3560== 
==3560== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3560== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Should I be getting a segmentation fault error?
Why am I not catching it with valgrind?

Kind regards

Comment: Valgrind isn't the right tool to detect undefined behavior like this.

Comment: `foo[5] = 12;` is Undefined Behaviour so you should have no expectations (for example the compiler is allowed to remove all the code in `main`).  However that said: try a larger value than 5, as `foo[5]` may be writing to part of the stack properly allocated by the compiler just not for your use.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what is good tool for this?

Comment: Perhaps [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), check your tool-chain to see if it's supported

Comment: @mysticsnake also note that UB doesn't necessarily causes a _segmentation fault_.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I be getting a segmentation fault error?

Irrelevant on if you should, you should not *expect* to be getting a segmentation fault in case your code is not valid.

Because `foo` is on stack, it is likely `foo + 5` is still inside stack memory region and *not* inside a protected memory region.

> Why am I not catching it with valgrind?

Valgrind is like a dynamic library that hooks C library calls, mostly for checking `malloc` dynamic allocation. It has no way of detecting out-of-bounds of arrays on stack.

> what is good tool for this?

Static analysis and code instrumentation. With gcc we have `-fanalyzer` and `-fsanitize=address`. There are also `clang-check` `cppcheck` etc.

```
+ g++ -fanalyzer -fsanitize=undefined 1.cpp
1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cpp:6:12: warning: stack-based buffer overflow [CWE-121] [-Wanalyzer-out-of-bounds]
    6 |     foo[5] = 12; // out of bounds
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~
  ‘int main()’: events 1-2
    |
    |    4 |     int foo[2] = {0};
    |      |         ^~~
    |      |         |
    |      |         (1) capacity: 8 bytes
    |    5 |     std::cout << foo[0] << std::endl;
    |    6 |     foo[5] = 12; // out of bounds
    |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |            |
    |      |            (2) out-of-bounds write from byte 20 till byte 23 but ‘foo’ ends at byte 8
    |
1.cpp:6:12: note: write of 4 bytes to beyond the end of ‘foo’
    6 |     foo[5] = 12; // out of bounds
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~
1.cpp:6:12: note: valid subscripts for ‘foo’ are ‘[0]’ to ‘[1]’
+ ./a.out
0
1.cpp:6:10: runtime error: index 5 out of bounds for type 'int [2]'
1.cpp:6:12: runtime error: store to address 0x7ffd904e0d64 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0x7ffd904e0d64: note: pointer points here
  00 20 01 00 00 00 00 00  88 0e 4e 90 fd 7f 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  50 98 23 42 16 7f 00 00
              ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example with gcc! Since the array it allocated to the stack, it would be easier for valgrind to catch it if it is on the heap?  Having `int* foo = new int[2]{0};` ?

Comment: Why ask me - just try it.

Comment: Asking you if for reasurance for someone who does not know. If I allocate it to the heap I will not get a segmentation fault. But Valgrind will tell me: `==5504== Invalid write of size 4
==5504==    at 0x1092B3: main (test.cpp:13)`

Comment: It should catch it, yes.